# MongoDB: Use $Match between latest N years

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I'm new with MongoDB. I want to use a **match** to only get the records that are between the last 2 years. Is there a way of doing this without hard coding it?

For example, this is the year 2023. But the latest year of the records of my collection is 2021. I want to get the records of the latest 2 years of **my collection**, not current year. So the range will be 2019-2021, **not** 2021-2023.

Is there a way of doing this without hard coding the years as strings?

I want to get this information so that I can use it in next stages

Currently I have this, hardcoded

````
      {
        $match: {
          fechaOrden: {
            $gte: ISODate("2018-01-01"),
            $lt: ISODate("2020-02-01"),
          }, 
        },
      },
    ] ```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$setWindowFields` to grab records in recent 2 years for a document. Then, use `$sort` + `$limit` to find the most recent record in whole collection and return the associated recent 2 years records.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  // compute latest records in 2 years
  {
    $setWindowFields: {
      sortBy: {
        dt: 1
      },
      output: {
        recentRecords: {
          $push: "$$ROOT",
          window: {
            range: [
              -2,
              0
            ],
            unit: "year"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  // find latest records in whole collection
  {
    "$sort": {
      dt: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 1
  },
  // cosmetics
  {
    "$unwind": "$recentRecords"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$recentRecords"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EheD1H0A_7f)